# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo in xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application on Google Play. I have integrated BugSense.  All was working fine suddenly i got 3 errors on **first line of first  control** in below xml. I dont know why this happening, on other android devices its working fine. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black_text"
    >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black_text"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeView_fav_shows"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/background_channel"
            />

        <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/gridview_channelView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:listSelector="@null"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

        </GridView>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/black_text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gridview_channelView"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/relativeView_fav_shows"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_favShows"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/fav_shows_normal"
                />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat Output.**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.microeyes.hindiserials/com.microeyes.hindiserials.ChannelMainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class
1   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
2   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
3   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
4   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
5   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

**Thankx**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This below tag should only be availabke in Top Parent Layout, Remove it from all other Laoyts/Views.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

It could be the reason for the error, Please post logcat output too.

Comment: @Ankit.. But why is error not occurring on all android devices?

Comment: What i told is recommendation, And this is the beauty of Android that all device don't behave same... Try it and let me know if it is causing problem. please add on create of ur activity too

Comment: that problem is still there.. i just received another crash report.. any further guesses why this happening?

Comment: on what phone you are getting this error. I have some phone available with me, if you can send out the app can help you out in debugging.